# refresh a text phrase in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, refresh

I try to make a small program in python 3 where a small message (ex hi) have the capability to be refreshed(blipping-flashing).So, I try to print the message and next to clear the screen and write it again(in the same position). Unfortunately I cant achieve it.. The program has as the follow lines:

```
os.system ('cls')
for i in range(100):
  os.system('cls')
  print('hi')
  print("\033")
  #print("\n" * 10)
```

Comment: What is `'\033'` supposed to do?

Comment: What is "blipping-flashing"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cls` clears the screen by making a bunch of new lines. You'll need something else

This is what I did:

```
import time

for i in range(100):
    print('     ' if i % 2 == 0 else 'blink', end='\r')
    time.sleep(0.1)
```